# Azure solution design guidelines

Tags: c#, azure, service, architecture

There are too many options to chose from in Microsoft Azure when planning application design. Azure itself not stands still, looks like many options added recently. I'm a pretty nooby solo developer so I need some entry points to choose architecture.

The application consists of next parts:

**1. Database**

Classic SQL database is already implemented with `Azure SQL database`.

**2. Server-side application.** *(architecture refactor needed)*

For now application is a .NET C#/WPF desktop application hosted on classic `Azure Virtual Machine` with Windows Server onboard.
This is an always-running scheduler that performs kind of tasks one by one.
Tasks are mainly long-running works getting some data from Web, CPU-bound proccessing with recieved data, working with the DB.

It feels like its kind of ancient and wrong design (having in mind amount of azure features):

a) The application really don't need a GUI, just ability to control scheduler's status required.

b) Logically some kind of tasks can be performed simultaneously, and some of them must wait others to finish before start. Now all of tasks performed one by one, that caused by virtual machine performance limit. I think there must be a way to achieve parallel working and control results on higher level of abstaction than inside desktop app. I wanna somehow move scheduling logic to level up. (Maybe IaaS->Paas goes here?)

**3. Client applications.**

Client applications. Registered users work with the DB.

Here questions:

Which server-side application design should be chosen in this case, what Azure features required?

Is there an Azure built-it abilities to manage registered users accounts, or only way is to implement it as a part of application?

Comment: Unfortunately this type of question doesn't fit on StackOverflow. Yes, there are lots of ways to solve a problem in Azure. Asking for which design should be chosen, though, is wide open to interpretation and opinion; there simply is no *right* answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you explore other storage options or SQL database is what you need?
lets start from scratch:

STORAGE:you can choose from 
1. Storage - Blob, Table, Queue, and File storage and disks for VM
2. SQL database - relational database service in the cloud based on the market leading Microsoft SQL Server engine, with mission-critical capabilities
3. Document DB - schema-free NoSQL document database service designed for modern mobile and web applications
4. StorSimple- integrated storage solution that manages storage tasks between on-premises devices and Microsoft Azure cloud storage
5. SQL data Warehouse- enterprise-class distributed database capable of processing petabyte volumes of relational and non-relational data
6. Redis Cache- High throughput, consistent low-latency data access to build fast, scalable applications
7. Azure Search- Search-as-a-service for web and mobile app development

SCHEDULAR: You can pick from
1. Virtual Machine
2. Cloud Service (worker role): you have more control over the VMs. You can install your own software on Cloud Service VMs and you can remote into them.
3. Batch: Cloud-scale job scheduling and compute management 
4. Service Fabric: distributed systems platform used to build scalable, reliable, and easily-managed applications for the cloud 
5. App Service: Scalable Web Apps, Mobile Apps, API Apps, and Logic Apps for any device

CLIENT: you can try out
1. Web Apps
2. Cloud Service (web role)

Use this link as one stop shop for all Azure services beautifully categorized based on functionality. From here you can pick and choose various services and amp it to your app's requirement.
MASTER LIST: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/

Comment: Sameeksha, thank you for the detailed answer! This is a kind of starting guide. Could you please also take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685728/migrating-specific-c-sharp-desktop-application-to-azure-paas-chosing-services) topic. I described my goal more specifically there. For now I need to choose between **Service Fabric** and **Azure Batch**.